# UIAlertView overlay now disappearing after dismiss

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have an annoying issue that I haven't been able to solve so far: some of the `UIAlertView` I use in my app fail to remove their overlay after being dismissed.

The app is simple, the only notable things that can impact on the UIAlertView are:

- I have a couple of overlapped custom views that form the background.
- The view controller is set as the delegate of the `UIAlertView`, but it implements only the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method.

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your whole code for showing and releasing the UIAlertView?

Comment: Also post a screenshot.